# Help with proof of Jensens inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove Jensens inequality, where $f \in L ^1(\mu) $, $a<f<b $ and $\phi $ convex on $(a,b)$, **but are stuck on the last part part of the proof.**

I define $t= \int _{\Omega } f d \mu $, where $\mu(\Omega ) =1$

Then define $\beta $ as the supremum of the left side of the inequlity  $\frac {\phi (t)- \phi(s)} {t-s } <\frac {\phi (u)- \phi(t)} {u-t } $ .

Now I can show that it follows that $\phi(f(x))\ge \phi(t)+\beta (f(x)-t) $, $a < f(x) < b $.

If I integrate this inequality I have $\int _{\Omega } (\phi(f(x)))\ge  \phi(\int _{\Omega} d \mu)+\int _{\Omega } (\beta (f(x)-t) )$

So that if *I could get the last term to disappear* I would be done! I don't know how I could do this though,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the part where you defined $\int_\Omega{f}d\mu=t$? Try to split up your integral $\beta\int_\Omega{(f(x)-t) d\mu}$ into a sum or difference of integrals, they are, after all, additive.

Comment: I cannot think of anything without going inte inequalities...

we have $\beta \int f(x) - \beta \int \int f $

Comment: Think of it more this way: We have $\int_\Omega{(f(x)-t)d\mu}=\int_\Omega{f(x)d\mu}-\int_\Omega{td\mu}$. Now we know that $\mu(\Omega)=1$, so what does that tell you about the second integral?

Comment: Ok, very simple, thanks!