# Help with understanding Proof of Jensen's inequality

Tags: measure-theory, jensen-inequality

I shall just reference another question [See the proof given here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349764/help-understanding-proof-on-jensens-inequality).
(Please see the link before reading the rest; I thought posting the same thing would be counterproductive.)

In the proof, when we take $ \beta $ to be the supremum on the left of the inequality, for $ s \in (a, t) $. Then that implies $ \beta \geq \frac{\phi(t)-\phi(s)}{t-s} = \frac{\phi(s)-\phi(t)}{s-t} $ for all $ s \in (a, t) $ $(1)$.
But in the next step of the proof says that $ \beta \leq \frac{\phi(s)-\phi(t)}{s-t}$ for all $ s \in (a, b)$. This is contradicting $(1)$. This is what I am not able to see. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to read the proof again slowly. Dividing an inequality by $s-t$ is not permissible if $s-t<0$. You have misquoted Rudin by doing this. To derive the inequality in his proof you will have to separately consider the cases $s<t$ and $s>t$.

Comment: But for real numbers, say $a,b,c,d$, $\frac{a-b}{c-d}=\frac{b-a}{d-c}$ (assuming denominators are not $0$). The sign of $s-t$ changes, but the numerator is nullifying the sign change, keeping the quantity invariant, isn't it? and $\beta$ is fixed.